# C++ getting real path of resource file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, path, resources, bmp

I have an external dll, who require a path as string to search the image.
Now I am able to save&load bitmap files from my resources, but I don't know how to get a path like "C:\test.bmp" from a resource file.

I already tried "test.bmp" (<- is the execute folder),
"resource\test.bmp" etc in upper, lowercase, + and without s and so on.

Any idea how I get a valid path to an image file in my resource?

```
testBMP = LoadBitmap(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDB_BITMAP2));
```

That works file, but is sadly not what I can use :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get a file-path to a resource in your module, you have to use the Windows API calls.  If you require the resource to have a file system path for the external dll you will need to extract it (this can be done at runtime) and save it into the file system.